# How do I get the result from a Java class to display in an Android activity?

Tags: java, android, android-edittext, particle-swarm

I have a Java class that uses PSO to calculate the best global solution for the optimisation of services that a user inputs in the main activity of a UI. When I run my UI, I have printed the bit combination calculation in the terminal using `System.out.println()`, however I need that same print to print in my EditText view in an activity called **SolutionActivity.java**.

Here is what my terminal shows me:

```
I/System.out: Particle value: 11.0
I/System.out: Particle bit string: [true, false, true, true]
I/System.out: Particle goodness: 5.0
I/System.out: Time spend: 2.8145
I/System.out: Iterations: 4.6209
I/System.out: Success: 3724.0
I/System.out: true false true true
```

Here is the code in the Java class (CustomUseCase.java) that prints this...

```
// ...

    this.found += (bpso.getFound() ? 1 : 0);
    this.iterations += bpso.getSolIterations(); //use the method in bpso to get number of iterations taken
    long end = System.currentTimeMillis() - start; //end time minus start time

    this.sumTimes += end; //override the time spent variable

    System.out.println("Particle value: "      + Particle.getValue(Particle.bestGlobal()));
    System.out.println("Particle bit string: " + Arrays.toString(Particle.bestGlobal()));
    System.out.println("Particle goodness: "   + customService.getGoodness(Particle.bestGlobal()));
}

System.out.println("Time spend: " + sumTimes/max);
System.out.println("Iterations: " + iterations/max);
System.out.println("Success: " + found);

boolean[] bestCombo = Particle.bestGlobal();

for(Boolean b: bestCombo){
    System.out.print(b + " ");
}

System.out.println();
```

Now I need the `System.out.print(b + " ");` printed in a EditText view in my `SolutionActivity`. The number boolean variables in `bestCombo[]` will vary depending on what the user inputs in the main activity, if the user inputs 3 services, then the bestCombo will have 5 elements, if the user inputs 6 services, the bestCombo will have 8 elements. Here is what it looks like at the moment...

```
public void setUserResults(){
    EditText userGlobal = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.userGlobal);
    EditText best = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.best);

    best.setText(); //i need the bestCombo solution to be input here!! e.g True False True False
}
```

Comment: What's your problem here? Why you don't use that setText?

Comment: How do I get the result from the other java class? Because the result isn't fixed, it can vary depending on the user input. If the user input is 2, then it can print 4 boolean answers (True False True True like my question) and if it is 8 then it can print 10 boolean answers. I want to know the best way to grab that result and print it in my activity, and the best format for it. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could have a method in CustomUseCase.java that calculates "bestCombo" and returns it as a String rather than printing it to the console. Something like:

```
class CustomUseCase {
    .
    .
    .

    public static String getBestCombo() {
        .
        .
        .

        boolean[] bestCombo = Particle.bestGlobal();

        String bestComboString = "";
        for (Boolean b : bestCombo){
            bestComboString = bestComboString + b + " ";
        }

        return bestComboString;
    }
}
```

And then call it:

```
String bestComboString = CustomUseCase.getBestComboString();
best.setText(bestComboString);
```

Comment: You are the real mvp

Answer (score 1):

I believe that what you are looking for is `TextChangedListener`. Set the first `EditText` with `addTextChangedListener`, and change the second `EditText` based on the input of the first one.

Code example:

```
userGlobal.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher(){
    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count){

    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int aft )                                                                          {

    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s){
        //call your function here for calculation
         best.setText(yourfunctioname(userGlobal.getText()));
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks Ricardo, 1 question, where it says call your function here, is this the function where it calculates the bestCombo? Kind regards

Comment: Yes. Basically your function should return a String (the result), so that you can set it to the EditText. If it is just a presentation Text you should consider using a `TextView` instead of an `EditText`

Comment: I have found the solution, thank you for your help :) gave you an up

Comment: The advantage of using `TextWatcher` is that it gives you the ability of updating something, in this case a second EditText once you edit the first, as I mentioned in my post.